# Vector images in android app automatically too bright

Tags: android

In my app, I added a page for themes setting, and made the vectors using Illustrator CC 2021, which were imported as xmls in Android Studio project.

The 1st vector is fine, but the rest 2 are gaining brightness, which is not suitable given that these vectors represent dark and light modes of the app.

Illustration here:
[image: screenshots]

It only happens in my physical android device, Redmi Note 8 with android 11.

My question is: Why does this happen, and what is the fix?

Comment: Post your XML code for both the activity/fragment and the vector drawable. Also, some devices have auto-brightness settings which can dim the entire screen. Not every device/emulator is going to look identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by my physical device's operator (MIUI)

Fixed by adding
`<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>` in styles